# Using React-PDF and Getting an error: Invalid pageIndex request onItemClick Event

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-pdf

I am using react-pdf and am getting the Error: Invalid pageIndex request when I click on an item in the outline.  Not sure what the issue is....

Here is the code for the onItemClick function.

```
  function onItemClick({ pageNumber: itemPageNumber}) {
    setPageNumber(itemPageNumber);
  }
```

Here is the Outline tag

```
<Outline className="width:100" onItemClick={onItemClick} />
```

Comment: VS code flags itemPageNumber  in the prop being passed into the onItemClick function as implicitly having type "any"...  Not about {pageNumber : itemPageNumber] being passed in... is it an object with property pageNumber and type? ...